# Como criar uma nova lista vazia ao clicar em "nova lista"

Tags: angularjs

Boa tarde,

Tenho um array de objetos e exibo os mesmos numa lista, na lista há um input para inserir novos objetos.
Quero fazer um botão onde criaria uma nova lista zerada e com o mesmo input para inserir novos objetos.
Como faria para que as listas exibissem apenas os objetos que foram inseridos nela?

Estou fazendo com AngularJs e não estou conseguindo criar essa nova lista, ela puxa os objetos da outra também.

Alguem tem alguma dica para que eu implemente essa lista?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi o seu problema, sem querer, você esbarrou em uma das funcionalidades mais interessantes do AngularJS: `A capacidade de manter um escopo bindado mesmo quando você muda ele de lugar`.

A resposta rápida é: Use `angular.copy()` para copiar sua lista para um novo lugar, assim o AngularJS cria um novo item no seu escopo sem linkar sua cópia com o escopo anterior.

Se você está interessado em ver um exemplo de como usar o angular.copy() em uma aplicação semelhante com essa que você está montando,  [veja esse plnkr q eu montei.](http://plnkr.co/edit/bNVOlcLM77L6pyyvlpsE?p=preview) Coloquei vários comentários no código para ajudar a compreender a lógica.

Eu usei [esse padrão de projetos](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/i18n/pt-BR.md) para montar o código desse exemplo. O padrão em questão foi desenvolvido por um cara chamado John Papa e é mantido por uma comunidade gigantesca, o que inclui profissionais do Google.

Comment: Obrigado, muito bom esse exemplo, foi bem o que eu precisava.